# Multibyte regex and hashtag parsing in PHP

Tags: php, regex, laravel, multibyte

I'm currently working on a project where users can tag their content using hashtags in the text area. When saving the post, I go through the content to find any hashtags, save them and relate them to the post model. It's all working fine except for one flaw, there is no multibyte support, which is a bug issue since this project will be international and with broad language support.

For instance, lets say I have this content in my post:

```
$content = 'This is my testing string, look at the hashtags and see that the multibyte ones are ignored. #php #regex #my #multibyte #åäö #öl #läsa #drickaöl #tags #are #being #ignored'
```

I'm currently using `preg_match_all` to fetch all the hashtags, like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(#\w+)/', $content, $matches);
```

Although, this will ignore any tag starting with a multibyte sign, such as **å, ä, or ö**, or simply break each tag wherever it encounters one.

People have been recommending the `mb_ereg()` method, but as far as I can tell, this only has support for getting a boolean result, indication whether or not your string matches the pattern.

You can have a look at my simple regex [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/mO7aB8/1).

Please help me understand and potentially fix this so that I can get this feature working properly.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `u` flag with your regex:

```
$re = '/#\w+/u';
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/bZonDV)

```
$re = '/#\w+/u'; 
$str = "This is my testing string, look at the hashtags and see that the multibyte ones are ignored. #php #regex #my #multibyte #åäö #öl #läsa #drickaöl #tags #are #being #ignored"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Perhaps, you also might want to use `\p{L}` (a Unicode letter category), but it does not seem necessary since `\w` with the `u` Unicode flag already matches all Unicode letters.
Here is a regex version with `\p{L}`:

```
$re = '/#[0-9_\p{L}]+/u';
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/wLOVll)

Comment: Side information: [`u` flag in PHP](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pcre/php_pcre.c#L385) turns on PCRE_UCP flags (along with PCRE_UTF8) in the PCRE library, so `\w` matches Unicode word character. Without PCRE_UCP, `\w` matches the usual ASCII word characters. http://ideone.com/I32cxm

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PCRE unicode propertiez: `\p{L}` and `\p{N}` for this:

```
preg_match_all('/(#[\p{L}\p{N}_]+)/u', $content, $matches);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/mO7aB8/4)